# Deny access to files in folder - allow acces from one file

Tags: .htaccess

I have a folder, /songs. All files inside this folder should be unaccessible. That should be easy to do.

But I want ONE file, player.php to have access to them. How can I do this?

I suppose .htaccess is the way to go.

Comment: Does this `player.php` access them by reading from the file system (the correct way to do this) or does it link them and require the browser to download it directly?

Comment: Ehmm, I don't really know (guess the first) but it is a new file, I'm creating, so it can be adjusted. Currently my thought is to play the files through HTML5 video/audio tag. The user just cannot have access to the file itself, but only to player.php.

Comment: If you're going to use HTML5, then the browser's going to need to be able to directly access those files

Comment: I'm open for other solutions... but to be clear: you're saying, that the above ain't possible?

Comment: You can check the referer field to see if a request for those files came from `player.php`, but the referer can be easily forged, so it's not really much protection. If you don't want those files from being accessed, create a script that reads the file and returns it to the browser. The script could check things like the referer, cookies, sessions or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's appreciated. Do you have a link to a guide/script that does something like that, or can you guide me in the right direction for more information?

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways to go about doing this, you can either make the files completely inaccessible from the internet or you can check the referer (sic).

The HTTP Referer is a request header field that is sometimes included with a request telling the web server where the request was referred from. For example, a page `index.html` could have an image `<img src="/foo.png">`. When the browser loads `index.html` and sees the image, it'll also load the image. The request made for the image will include `http://example.com/index.html` as the referer before that page is what referred the browser to load the image. The problem with the referer is that (like most HTTP request headers) it can be easily forged. This means that someone who wants to download all of your songs can just fake the referer to say it came from `player.php`. This is probably the easiest to implement:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/player\.php
RewriteCond $1 !player\.php
RewriteRule ^songs/(.*)$ - [L,F]
```

Those rules would go in the htaccess file in your document root. Or if you want to put it in the `songs` folder, remove the `songs/` part of the rule's regular expression.

The first solution is the best because it makes it so the files are inaccessible except through a script of your design. So something like (we'll call it `load.php`):

```
<?php

// make whatever checks here to ensure it's ok to send the file to the browser

$name = $_GET['name'];
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

// Change the header to whatever your file's mime type is
header("Content-Type: audio/mp3");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

fpassthru($fp);
exit;

?>
```

Then you can access those files by going to: `http://example.com/load.php?name=song.mp3`. As for what checks you need to do, you can check the referer by looking at `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. You can set a UUID or session cookie from `player.php` and then check it in `load.php`.

Then you can deny access to your files using something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !(player|load)\.php
RewriteRule ^songs/(.*)$ - [L,F]
```

to deny access to anything that isn't player.php or load.php

Comment: Thank you so much! The second script (with a load.php) sounds great. Can I just put a simple deny script in the htaccess of /songs/ to make it inaccesible from other than the load.php-solution?

Comment: @ChristianBundgaard you can use a simple rule, or you can move the files outside of your webroot. (see edit)